Sum of entries of the inverse of a positive definite matrix $I_{\ell}+A_1 A_1^T+A_2 A_2^T$
Let $A_1$ be an $\ell \times n$ matrix and $A_2$ be an $\ell \times m$ matrix, where $\ell \geqslant n, m$. The entries of $A_1$ and $A_2$ are only 0 's and 1 's such that

Each row has exactly one 1 , and
Each column has at least one 1 .
Let $A_1^{\prime}$ be an $(\ell+1) \times n$ matrix formed by adding to $A_1$ a $k$ th row that consists of one 1 with all other entries being 0 's, where $k \leqslant \ell+1$. Similarly let $A_2^{\prime}$ be an $(\ell+1) \times m$ matrix formed by adding to $A_2$ a $k$ th row that consists of one 1 with all other entries being 0 's. The position of 1 in each added row is arbitrary and independent.

Prove or disprove: The sum of all entries of $\left(I_{\ell+1}+A_1^{\prime} A_1^{\prime T}+A_2^{\prime} A_2^{\prime T}\right)^{-1}$ is greater than or equal to the sum of all entries of $\left(I_{\ell}+A_1 A_1^T+A_2 A_2^T\right)^{-1}$.
Possibly useful result: $I_{\ell}+A_1 A_1^T+A_2 A_2^T$ is positive definite (since $I$ is positive definite and the two products are both positive semidefinite).
If you cannot prove or disprove the problem above, try a simpler alternative problem: Instead of allowing $k$ to be any number in $\{1, \ldots, \ell+1\}$ (so that the new rows can be inserted in any place), set $k=\ell+1$ (so that the new rows are added to the bottoms of the matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ ).
